# Connect to USB receipt printer from WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, usb, receipt

I'm stuck at a task I have got, I'm trying to connect and print to a USB receipt printer, but have not been successful yet. The company has bought a kiosk stand, basically a windows based computer with touch screen and printer, from China.
I'm building a WPF (C#) application for this kiosk stand, that should be able to print receipts.

The kiosk stand came with a tool to test the printer
[image]
Which is working fine on the kiosk stand itself, but when I connect the printer to my personal computer, it won't work.

The printer shows up under "Devices and Printers" as "Unspecified" on both the kiosk stand and my personal computer, with name "JRSVC Printer"
[image]

And on both the kiosk stand and my computer, the printer seems to use a driver called "usbprint.sys"
[image]

I have tried to connect to the printer from C#:
[image]
But I'm only able to find printers that are not "Unspecified".

So I'm pretty stuck to as how I can connect and print with this USB Printer. The "Print Test Tool" can easily print from the kiosk stand itself (but not from my own pc?), so it's working even it's under "Unspecified" on the kiosk stand.

The physical printer looks like this:
[image]

And here is a link to the software that came with the kiosk stand:
http://www.filedropper.com/chinaprintersoftware

If someone could point me in the right direction, to as how I can connect and print from a WPF (C#) application, I will much appreciate that!

Comment: Can you print on it from windows? Like from notepad?

Comment: I can print from the kiosk stand itself, with the "Print test tool"-software, shown on the first image. I can't print from Notepad, since the printer does not show up on the list of printers, that Notepad can use

Comment: Sounds like drivers issue...

Comment: did you try sending serial data to the printer via usb?
it might not be a printer with a driver but a serial one 
dont you have a manual or anything to reffer to?

Comment: No manual or manufacturer homepage, only Chinese documents and test tool, which all is linked above.
No I have not tried sending serial data to the printer, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm struggling with it too.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that usbprint isn't a "regular" printer driver in the sense that most people are familiar with, it's a low-level driver used to interface directly to the hardware. This means you can't print the usual way via a GDI interface, you don't get most of the benefits of Windows printing and you can't print from a regular windows application.

The first thing to do is take a look at the [USBPRINT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/programming-considerations-for-usbprint), namely the parts on [how to print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/printing-a-print-job). If I were doing this myself I'd knock up a quick C++ application just to get the printer working and then either wrap that in a managed C++ library that my WPF app can consume or, preferably, interface directly via DLLImport.

As far as what data to send, that depends on the printer. There are a variety of standards so you'll have to either get the documentation for it or look at what the demo apps are sending. Given how old this thing apparently is it might support regular LPT1 plain-text and escape sequences.

If at all possible you should try and find the documentation for it anyway if for no other reason than to see if it has any config options. I've spent many years developing WPF kiosk software for a variety of sectors and most printers I've seen support at least some kind of serial emulation capability. In fact before doing anything else you should probably check your Device Manager, in particular the 'Ports (COM and LPT)' section. If it shows up there then your job just got much easier.

UPDATE: actually I've just gone and looked at the documentation, are you sure this thing isn't showing up as a serial port on the kiosk itself? Because from the docs it looks like it supports it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying! There is no documentation, the manufacture doesn't have a homepage, all I got was the files I linked above.
The printer DOES show up under "Device Manager"->"COM & LPT", [here is a screenshot](http://i66.tinypic.com/2ykhyrt.jpg)
Does that help me? -I hope, because I have no C++ experience

Comment: Ok, well your screenshot shows 4 com ports and 1 lpt port. Which one disappears when you pull the plug on your printer?

Comment: I assumed the "Printer Port (LPT1)" would be the printer, but it does not disappear/reappear when plug and unplug :/ But the one called "USB Printing Support" under "Universal Serial Bus controllers" does. [Screenshot](http://i65.tinypic.com/2a5ezia.jpg)

Comment: Ok, in that case I suspect you're going to have to either figure out how to enable serial emulation from their setup utility (assuming it supports it) or try to find some existing C# code that let's you interop those USBPRINT functions. Alternatively, wrapping an interface to it yourself shouldn't take more than half an hour or so, [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8) shows how it's done.

Comment: Again, this is all speculation. These devices can be a bit tricky to get working when you don't have proper documentation, sometimes I have to try a variety of approaches to figure out how a particular device works. If I were you I would also contact icod directly, they'll often have resources not in the main package, or possibly even put you in touch with an engineer who speaks English.